# Subject vs. Object marking for whoever?

Tags: pronouns, grammatical-case, whoever-vs-whomever

I know similar questions have been asked before, but I'm having trouble reconciling the following sentence, received in an email:

> Can we ask whomever is your contact there to email us a job so we can check backward compatibility?

I could understand using objective case if the sentence were "can we ask (him) to email...", but I get tripped up considering "whomever" to be the subject of "(he) is your contact there".

Comment: Edited the title: *subjective* and *objective* (without a subsequent "case") have meanings that are almost entirely divorced from *subject* and *object*, and you seem to be asking about the latter, not the former.

Comment: @Martha: Thanks.  I was at sort of a loss and the word "case" didn't surface...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The part that tricked the original writer is that "whomever is your contact there" is a noun clause that is collectively the object of "can we ask...".  The rule is that, in a situation like that, you're supposed to look *inside* the clause for your objective/subjective case, though, so actually the sentence should use "whoever", as you suspected.

Comment: that's what I thought, and that's why I thought it.

Answer (score 5):

I think most prescriptive sources with an opinion on the matter would consider this to be a hypercorrection. The logic is that the clause must have a subject, and in the absence of anything else, "whoever" is deemed the subject. The hypercorrection probably occurs because:

- "whomever" is an incredibly rare word, and the choice between "who" and "whom" is probably no longer part of the naturally acquired syntax of English;
- there are other, clearly grammatical, instances of "exceptional case marking" where the subject of a clause takes on the objective case due to influence from outside the clause ("they hoped for *him* to be available").

If you're ever wondering whether to distinguish between "whoever" and "whomever", I would suggest a really simple rule:

> Don't ever use "whomever": it's a pointless and old-fashioned.

I would suggest not getting bogged down in spurious debates about "subject" and "object" here: it's nowadays perfectly natural English to say: "I'll give it to whoever", "Pick whoever", "Pick whoever you like" etc.