# "10 points to whomever knows the answer" or whoever?

Tags: whoever-vs-whomever

Should it be "10 points to whomever knows the answer" or "10 points to whoever knows the answer"?

Comment: Related question, [Subject vs. Object marking for whoever?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14182/subject-vs-object-marking-for-whoever).

Comment: @andrew leach While it is sort of a duplicate, this is a bit more complicated since the preposition *to* immediately precedes *whoever*. The noun clause is the object of the preposition. That does not trump the grammatical role of *whoever*, but it adds to the confusion and might warrant an explanation.