# Use of Whoever and Whomever

Tags: pronouns, whoever-vs-whomever

We are debating the use of Whoever vs Whomever in this sentence "Thanks to whoever fixed this".

What is the correct form?
- Thanks to whoever fixed this
- Thanks to whomever fixed this!

Any explanation will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Related: [What’s the rule for using “who” and “whom” correctly?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56/what-s-the-rule-for-using-who-and-whom-correctly)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Whoever" Vs. "Whomever"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84376/whoever-vs-whomever) The question [" '10 points to whoever knows the answer' or '10 points to whomever knows the answer'?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/309754/10-points-to-whomever-knows-the-answer-or-whoever) looks a closer match on the surface; it was closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

**WHOEVER**

There is some confusion here because whomever is used as an object. However, in the case the object of the sentence is not just "whomever/whoever" but the phrase "whoever did this".

Answer (score 3):

The simplest and easiest rule to follow for using *whomever* is this one:

- **Don't ever** use *whomever*. **Ever**.

Here are two good reasons for this rule (which you will not find in most grammar books):

- Native speakers don't know how to use *whomever* correctly, and make mistakes all the time.
- *Whoever* works in all situations, just like *who* works instead of *whom* in all situations.

There used to be [well-understood grammar rules](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/517249/15299) for usage of *whom* and its ilk. They are no longer well-understood because they have not been taught  in Anglophone educational systems for a century.

Nowadays many English speakers (at least in the USA) think that *whom* (and *whomever*) are just [fancy versions that one should use when being extra formal and official](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001437.html), sort of like dressing up special for church on Sunday. That's silly, of course, but many people believe it and practice it in their own speech.

Many of them would in fact be willing to correct anyone who used *whom* or *whomever* wrongly, by their standards. This means that even if you **do** know how to use these words correctly, and do so, somebody will be mentally correcting **your** grammar. And this is not the only silly grammatical rule around, as who knows better than ELU participants?

Answer (score 0):

*Thanks to whoever fixed this* is correct.

*Whoever* or *whomever* will head up a dependent clause that is an island unto itself. The clause is not affected by its role in the sentence (which could be—for example—subject, subject complement, or object).

In the clause, *whoever* will be a subject or a subject complement. *Whomever* will be an object.

In your sentence, the clause *whoever fixed this* is preceded by a preposition, so the clause is the object of a preposition.

Ignore that.

Pull the whole clause out and make sure it works by itself . . .

It's going to need a subject, a verb, and whatever else is necessary to make it complete. Like this:

> *Thanks to whoever fixed this.*
>
> *whoever fixed this* = *he fixed this*

*Whoever* (like *he*) is the subject of the verb, *fixed* is the verb, and *this* is the object of the verb. Good to go. Put the clause back where you found it.

Let's try something a little different:

> *Give thanks to whomever you see.*
>
> *whomever you see*  = *him you see* = *you see him*

*You is the subject of the verb, *see* is the verb, and *whomever* (like *him*) is the object of the verb. Good to go. Put the clause back where you found it.

One more thing . . .

> *Thank you, whoever you are.*
>
> *whoever you are* = *he you are* = *you are he*

*Whoever is a subject complement for *you*. (When a pronoun follows a linking verb as a subject complement, it will be a subject pronoun.)

Clauses can get complicated, and it can be hard to figure out what's a subject and what's an object. If you're in that deep, refer to @JohnLawler's answer.

<sub>Further reading: [‘Whoever’ vs. ‘Whomever’](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/volokh-conspiracy/wp/2014/08/28/whoever-vs-whomever/)</sub>